# How to compile the source code of Apache IoTDB under `service.rpcthrift` and `IClientRPCService` directories?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

How to compile the source code of Apache IoTDB under `service.rpcthrift` and `IClientRPCService` directories?
I am trying to compile the source code of Apache IoTDB. I want to know that if I want to compile source code for `service.rpcthrift` and `IClientRPCService` directories, can I just modify the source code directly? Will the changes take effect? Or what should I do to save my changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These source codes cannot be modified directly in Apache IoTDB. If you want to modify the source code, you need to change the definition file and then regenerate the Java class.